# Calculating Mbps in Prometheus from cumulative total

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a metric in Prometheus called `unifi_devices_wireless_received_bytes_total`, it represents the cumulative total amount of bytes a wireless device has received. I'd like to convert this to the download speed in Mbps (or even MBps to start).

I've tried:

```
rate(unifi_devices_wireless_received_bytes_total[5m])
```

Which I *think* is saying: "please give me the rate of bytes received per second", over the last 5 minutes, based on the documentation of `rate`, [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate()).

But I don't understand what "over the last 5 minutes" means in this context.

In short, how can I determine the Mbps based on this cumulative amount of bytes metric? This is ultimately to display in a Grafana graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `rate(unifi_devices_wireless_received_bytes_total[5m]) / 1000 / 1000`

> But I don't understand what "over the last 5 minutes" means in this context.

It's the average over the last 5 minutes.

Comment: This produces undesirable results. If I download 100MB worth of data in ten seconds, the metric you provided says that the high mbps lasted five minutes. Thus, my confusion with using `[5m]` in this context.

Comment: Should `5m` align with how frequently Prometheus scrapes the metric?

Comment: It should be at least 4x the scrape interval, so it's resilient to failed scrapes.

Comment: This produces inaccurate results in Grafana. Is it possible 5 minute average is making the data incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

The [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function returns the **average** per-second increase rate for the counter passed to it. The **average** rate is calculated over the lookbehind window passed in square brackets to `rate()`.

For example, `rate(unifi_devices_wireless_received_bytes_total[5m])` calculates the average per-second increase rate over the last 5 minutes. It returns lower than expected rate when 100MB of data in transferred in 10 seconds, because it divides those 100MB by 5 minutes and returns the average data transfer speed as `100MB/5minutes = 333KB/s` instead of `10MB/s`.

Unfortinately, using `10s` as a lookbehind window doesn't work as expected - it is likely the `rate(unifi_devices_wireless_received_bytes_total[10s])` would return nothing. This is because `rate()` in Prometheus expects at least two raw samples on the lookbehind window. This means that new samples must be written at least every 5 seconds or more frequently into Prometheus for `[10s]` lookbehind window. The solution is to use [irate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#irate) function instead of `rate()`:

```
irate(unifi_devices_wireless_received_bytes_total[5m])
```

It is likely this query would return data transfer rate, which is closer to the expected 10MBs if the interval between raw samples (aka `scrape_interval`) is lower than 10 seconds.

Unfortunately, it isn't recommended to use `irate()` function in general case, since it tends to return jumpy results when refreshing graphs on big time ranges. Read [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.

So the ultimate solution is to use [rollup_rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup_rate) function from [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - the project I work on. It reliably detects spikes in counter rates by returning the minimum, maximum and average per-second increase rate across all the raw samples on the selected time range.